# Expecting http://127.0.0.1:5000/; But only 'Process finished with exit code 0'

Tags: flask, pycharm

New to Python. Use Pycharm to test Flask simpliest web application. 
Supposed to output: http://127.0.0.1:5000/
But I got 'Process finished with exit code 0'

Please check out the images below.

Code

[image]

Console

[image]

Configuration

[image]

Comment: copy and paste code and console outputs not images of code.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found the solution on reddit:
remove ALL spaces before and after '='
Type in Console:
Line 1: set FLASK_APP=hello.py
Line 2: flask run

Answer (score 0):

Process finished with exit code 0 means your program has compiled successfully without any errors. Pycharm returns 0 when it has found no errors.

Answer (score 0):

in picture 3, where is the "hello.py"? does your app file is named as "FLASK_APP.py"?